# Как получить calback_data в dp.callback_query_handler в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

есть код который должен:

1. при отправке команды "Загрузить тест" выводить n количество инлайн кнопок
2. при нажатии на любую кнопку вывзывается callback handler и в нем надо получить callback_data

```
async def upload_file(message: types.Message):
    kb_lectures_list = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    lectures_name_list = lectures_df["video_name"].tolist()

    for lecture_name in lectures_name_list:
        button = InlineKeyboardButton(lecture_name, callback_data=lecture_name)
        print(button.callback_data)
        kb_lectures_list.row(button)

    await message.answer("выберите лекцию, к которой нужно прикрепить тест", reply_markup=kb_lectures_list)
    await Upload_f.file_name.set()


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data,state=Upload_f.file_name)
async def get_file_name(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    answer = call.message.text
    print(call.message.text)
    await state.update_data(file_name=answer)
    await call.message.answer("отправьте файл с тестом")
    await Upload_f.file_id.set()
```

Как это сделать? Мой код при выводе file name выводит "выберите лекцию, к которой нужно прикрепить тест"

Answer (score 0):

у call есть метод data он выводит callback_data
`print(call.data)`

Answer (score 0):

```
async def upload_file(message: types.Message):
    kb_lectures_list = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    lectures_name_list = lectures_df["video_name"].tolist()

    for lecture_name in lectures_name_list:
        button = InlineKeyboardButton(lecture_name, callback_data=lecture_name)
        print(button.callback_data)
        kb_lectures_list.row(button)
```

Данные callback_data должны быть указаны в ковычках:

```
button = InlineKeyboardButton(lecture_name, callback_data='lecture_name')
```

При нажатии на инлайн-кнопку callback_query_hanlder ловит дату и по ней запускает машину состояний:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='lecture_name', state =None)#начальный хэндлер, нет никаких состояний, реагирует на дату с инлайн кнопки
async def start(call: types.CallbackQuery) #ловит первое состояние state 
    await Upload_f.file_id.set()#принимает это состояние
    await message.reply('Отправь файл')

@dp.message_handler(content_types:['file'], state=FSMAfmin.file_id) #обрабатывает это состояние state, как файл
async def load_file(message: types.Message, state = FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['file_id'] = message.file[0].file_id #насчет этой строчки не уверен, вроде файл импортируется также, как фото, но это не точно
    await FSMAdmin.next()#переходит на следующее состояние, по аналогии ловит состояния и обрабатывает их


await state.finish() #конец машины состояний, всё, что Вы хотите сделать с данными нужно записать до этой команды, после неё машина отчищается
```

Надеюсь, правильно понял и помог